# trying to concatenate two layers in keras with the same shape giving error in shapes matching

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am trying to build a multi-input multi-output model using [keras functional api](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) and I am following their code but I got that error:

> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching
>   shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 50),
>   (None, 50, 1)]

I have skipped the Embedding layer, here is the code:

```
def build_model(self):
    main_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len, 1), name='main_input')
    print(main_input.shape)
    # seq_len = 50
    # A LSTM will transform the vector sequence into a single vector,
    # containing information about the entire sequence
    lstm_out = LSTM(self.seq_len,input_shape=(self.seq_len,1) )(main_input)
    self.auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)

    auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len,1), name='aux_input')
    print(auxiliary_input.shape)
    x = concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])

    # We stack a deep densely-connected network on top
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

    # And finally we add the main logistic regression layer
    main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)
    self.model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])
    print(self.model.summary())
    self.model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',
              loss_weights=[1., 0.2])
```

I got that error in the concatenation step, although printing the shape of both layers are (?,50,1).
I do not know exactly why I got this, and what is the exact error in the input_shape of the first layer and why it does not give me the same shape as it should be using `print(main_input.shape)`, and how to solve it ?

> UPDATE:

I found a solution for the error by changing the shape of the second input layer

```
auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len,), name='aux_input')
```

so now they can concatenate smoothly, but still not clear to me why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second input, you specified before the bug that,

```
input_shape = (50,1)# seq_length=50
```

This means final shape is:

```
(None,50,1)
```

Now, when the first input passes through `LSTM` , since you didn't specify `return_sequences=True` it will return a tensor of shape `(batch_size, units)` viz. `(None, 50)` which you are concatenating with the above mentioned `(None, 50, 1)`

Your error went away because you changed the input shape for the second input as `(50,)` so the final shape becomes `(None,50)` which matches with output of `LSTM` and hence it concatenated smoothly